# convert "2013-07-21T10:31:00" string to "20-Jul-2013" format string

Tags: java, android, android-studio

how to convert "2013-07-21T10:31:00" string to "20-Jul-2013" format string.

Currently i am getting a string output from web service "2013-07-21T10:31:00" i want to convert this string to "20-Jul-2013" format string.

Comment: Well it sounds like you need to use one `SimpleDateFormat` to parse, and another `SimpleDateFormat` to format. What have you tried?

Comment: @JonSkeet i 'm very new to android and java

Comment: @Vinoth: So what research did you perform before asking the question? Did you search Stack Overflow or the rest of the web for converting date formats?

Comment: Thank you all..
i got result using http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-string-to-date-java/ this link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
public  String FormatDate(String dateString) {

        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
            Date d = sd.parse(dateString);
            sd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd");
            System.out.println(sd.format(d));
            return sd.format(d);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
    String strDate="2013-07-21T10:31:00";
    DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss");
    Date date=df.parse(strDate);
    df=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    System.out.println(df.format(date));
```

Live [Demo](http://ideone.com/RdmI7J)

Answer (score 1):

you should use this also:

```
String date="2013-07-21T10:31:00";
DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss");
inputFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
Date parsed = new Date();
try
{
    parsed = inputFormat.parse(date);
}
catch (ParseException e)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
String outputText = outputFormat.format(parsed);
```